# Android-How to get User info from Firebase after logging in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

With my current login activity, I can log in just fine, however I need to get Uid throughout my project.

This is my current login activity:

```
   //authenticate user
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // there was an error
                            if (password.length() < 6) {
                                lPass.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

How do I get the user Uid from the login and have it be accessible to all my other activities? 
Thanks

Comment: get uid from FirebaseInstance and save it in preference

Comment: If I save it in preference, can I retrieve it back from any activity?

Comment: yes anywhere, even after closing app using shared preference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get user info from the `FirebaseUser` object. In order to achieve this, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to add this in your `onCreate` method after your code.

Comment: `firebaseUser` is the object of `FirebaseUser` class. Please check my updated ansqwer and keep me posted.

Comment: ok, I've updated it. Should I now save userId to sharedpreferences so I can use it across my project?

Comment: If you need the `userId` in more than one activity you can use an `intent`. If you need it across the whole project, yes, it's a good practice to store in `SharedPreferences`.  So, if you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting my answer and giving a +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

This line will give you the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to get all details available for user logged in from firebase.

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
// User Name
mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
// User ID
mFirebaseUser.getUid();
// Email-ID
mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
// User-Profile (if available)
mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FirebaseAuth you can get user uid,

```
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
Log.d(TAG," UserId : "+firebaseUser.getUid()+" , DisplayName"+firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
```